# is a weighted linear regression needed to account for number of observations

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, binary-data

I have a data in the following format:
Y        X/Z
.5       1/4
.6       3/10
.4       4/16
.3       1/2
.2       20/40
where I make one observation of Y for Z measurements of a binary variable, of which X are positive. 
I want to show that there is a correlation between Y and the proportion of X/Z. Would it be accurate to run a simple linear regression for Y and X/Z or should each X/Z be weighted by the number of observations Z?

Comment: As an approximation you could do this, but it would be better to use a generalized linear model (GLM) with Binomial response.